# Objective C : calculate and display time to millisecond

Tags: objective-c, math

**Full Disclosure**: I am a mathematical moron

```
int hours = totalSeconds / (60 * 60);
int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
//int milliseconds ???
calculatedExposureTime.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds];
```

Say `totalSeconds` was a fraction of a second (0.000156), how do I calculate and display time down to the millisecond?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
double seconds = fmod(totalSeconds, 60.0);
... [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d:%02d:%06.3f", hours, minutes, seconds];
```

BTW, 0.000156 is less than one millisecond, so it will display as `0.000`.

Comment: Thank you Marcelo, told you i was a bit of a moron. Appreciate your help